# Python vs R elapsed time

Tags: python, r, time, elapsed

In `R.studio`, to measure the real time passed since the program started running I use

```
t1=proc.time()
proc.time()-t1
```

In python which is the corresponding function? I want to compare them so, they need to measure the same think in the same units.
I have used `time.time()`, `time.clock()` and `os.times()` already.

Using `os.times()` : `(2.85, 0.08, 0.0, 0.0, 1480873284.06)`
Using `time.time()`: `8.46453595161`
Using `time.clock()`: `2.620683`

The `proc time` in R gives:

```
user:0.015   system:0.001   elapsed:0.029
```

I'm interested in the corresponding elapsed time in Python.

Comment: what is the problem ? Did `time.time()` give error message ? What do you expect ? We don't know what result you get with `R`.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope it is more clear now. Thanks

Comment: `Linux / Bash` has function `time` which gives similar result `real 0m0.002s user 0m0.000s sys 0m0.000s` - you call it `time program_or_script`

Comment: Python has only [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to run simple code many times and get average time.